# Do jquery and backbone conflict with one another?

Tags: jquery

This may be an ignorant question - So jquery using the "$" to call jquery functions. It appears as though backbone uses the dollar sign as well when calling "el". Is this a conflict?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a conflict because in jQuery $ refers to `jQuery` (so $('a') means jQuery('a')) whereas in Backbone $el is just the variable name given to the jQuery-type root element of a Backbone View instance. It's the same as writing

```
$this = $(this);
```

Beginning the variable name with a $ is just a convention that is followed to indicate that the variable is a jQuery object(or a jQuery wrapped set)

Answer (score 1):

`$el` is a reference to the cached jQuery object for the view's element.

See Backbone documentation: http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el

Comment: Can you explain this a little more. Does this mean backbone is assuming I have jquery cached on my computer. What if I dont?

Comment: No, it's just a handy way of referencing your el for when you need to use jQuery functions. `$el` is the same as `$(el)`.

Answer (score 1):

In case of jQuery, $ is just an alias for JQuery and can be used interchangeably, as shown below.

```
$( document ).ready(function(  ) {  // Code });
```

or

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function(  ) {  // Code });
```

There are actually many libraries, which use $ as variable or function name. If you are using any such library with JQuery, you can return the control of $ back to that library and create another alias for JQuery, as shown below.

```
var q = jQuery.noConflict();
q( document ).ready(function(  ) {  // Code });
```